# SSL Warning in Kiwi TCMS within Kubernetes Cluster

Tags: kiwi-tcms

I am using NGINX to route traffic to certain services in my Kubernetes Cluster. It is also handling certifications etc. Internally, I am forwarding to the http port of the Kiwi Docker container (port 80). That's why I am getting the "You are not using a secure connection. See documentation and enable SSL.!" warning, even though the connection is secured.

Is there a way to hide this warning? (ideally without changing the source code, maybe there is a setting or so? I am having trouble building my own docker image, not sure what the problem with that is. Have pulled the last image from the Kiwi dockerhub account instead)

Answer (score 0):

> Internally, I am forwarding to the http port of the Kiwi Docker container (port 80).

Is there any reason why you aren't using HTTPS between Nginx and Kiwi TCMS? That won't hurt, right?

> Is there a way to hide this warning?

Either use HTTPS everywhere or configure the setting `SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER`, see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#secure-proxy-ssl-header